# Is the weak interaction Lagrangian invariant under parity transformations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, parity, electroweak

The weak interaction term in the Lagrangian reads

$$ \bar   \Psi  \gamma_\mu P_L   \Psi W^\mu. $$

Under parity transformations, because of $\Psi \rightarrow \gamma_0 \Psi$ and $\gamma_5 \rightarrow - \gamma_5$, which yields $P_L = \frac{1-\gamma_5}{2} \rightarrow \frac{1+\gamma_5}{2}=P_R$ the weak interaction term tranforms into

$$ \bar   \Psi  \gamma_\mu P_L   \Psi W^\mu \rightarrow \bar   \Psi \gamma_0  \gamma_\mu P_R \gamma_0  \Psi W^\mu = \bar   \Psi \gamma_0  \gamma_\mu \gamma_0  P_L  \Psi W^\mu  =  \bar   \Psi   \gamma_\mu  P_L  \Psi W^\mu $$

**Am I making a computational error here or is the weak interaction Lagrangian invariant under parity transformations?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that $\gamma_5$ doesn't intrinsically change sign under parity.  Also, don't forget that under parity the spatial components of $W_\mu$ change sign.
And also $\gamma^0 \gamma^\mu \gamma^0 \neq \gamma^\mu$.

Comment: Wow that would be a lot of errors. Firstly, do you have any reference on $\gamma_5 \neq - \gamma_5$? Secondly, I don't think that we have under parity transformations $W_i \rightarrow - W_i$,  because following the same logic $A_i \rightarrow - A_i$ and the Lagrangian for electromagnetic interactions, wouldn't be invariant under parity transformations.

Comment: Okay, we have $W_i \rightarrow - W_i$, which yields an invariant Lagrangian for electromagnetism, too because in the Weyl Basis: $\gamma^0 \gamma^\mu \gamma^0 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 &  \sigma_\mu \\ \bar{\sigma}_\mu & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \sigma_\mu & 0   \\ 0 & \bar{\sigma}_\mu   \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 &   \bar{\sigma}_\mu \\  \sigma_\mu  & 0 \end{pmatrix} $. This means $\gamma_0 \rightarrow \gamma_0$ and $\gamma_i \rightarrow - \gamma_i$.

Comment: The minus sign from $\gamma_i \rightarrow - \gamma_i$ cancels the minus sign from $W_i \rightarrow - W_i$.

Comment: For example in this book: http://books.google.de/books?id=2Tf6AwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA420&ots=ikoVwH1Wnw&dq=palash%20pal%20left%20chiral%20spinor&hl=de&pg=PA156#v=onepage&q&f=false on page 156 eq. 6.26 it is written that under parity transformations $\gamma_5 \rightarrow - \gamma_5$ . Therefore, my question remains unsanswered...

Comment: Read the book (and other resources) carefully: none of the gamma matrices on their own change sign under parity.  It is the whole *bilinear* $\bar\psi F \psi$ that transforms, and how it transforms is to be derived from the transformation law $\Psi\rightarrow\gamma^0\Psi$ alone.

Comment: You're right about that. We have $\gamma^0 \gamma^5 \gamma^0=-\gamma_5$ and thats where the book gets $\gamma_5 \rightarrow - \gamma_5$ from. Nevertheless, I think that there must be an intrinsically sign change for $\gamma_5$, because a left-chiral field stays a left-chiral field under parity transformations: $\Psi_L = P_L \Psi =\begin{pmatrix}\chi_L\\0\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \Psi_L^P = \begin{pmatrix}0\\\chi_L  \end{pmatrix} \neq \Psi_R$ as explained in more detail here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/151352/is-parity-really-violated-even-though-neutrinos-are-massive

Comment: Although I beg to differ, I think this is really the point where the textbooks conclude that parity is violated by this term in the Lagrangian. Thank you!

Comment: hmm.. you seem to be under the impression that texts claim that parity changes a left-chiral field into an all together *different* right-chiral field, when what parity really does is to re-express the same left-chiral field differently.  While you are essentially correct about what parity does, no text claims that parity changes the identity of a field.

Comment: The question of whether weak interactions are invariant under parity is really asking whether the Lagrangian remains invariant once the all the fields have been written in a parity transformed manner.  Mathematically, that's all there is to it.